# Let $B_n$ be the set of all n-tuples $(a_1, a_2, ...,a_n)$ where $a_i \in {0,1}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $B_n$ be the set of all n-tuples $(a_1, a_2, ...,a_n)$ where $a_i \in {0,1}$ Let $A$ be the set of all sequences whose elements are digits $0$ or $1$ Does $ A = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}  B_n$? We do this by examining the elements of $A$. Suppose we have a list of the elements of $A$ as such $$a_1 = 010111011...$$ $$a_2= 010110011...$$ $$a_3=1000111100...$$ $$\vdots$$ $$a_n=110011100...$$ We can always find a new sequence that is not included in our list by taking the digit in the place of the term of the sequence and replacing a zero with a one and vice versa. This means that $A$ is not countable, i.e., it is uncountable. On the other hand.. I was right in the middle of writing this proof this way and then I realized that they are the same set. Is it not true that these are actually the same sets?

Comment: First of all, they're not the same set because the contain different kinds of objects.  An element $(a_1,a_2)$ of $B_2$ is not "a sequence whose elements are digits $0$ or $1$" since it only has two elements.  What I think you're trying to decide, however, is whether there is a **bijection** between the union $\bigcup B_n$ and $A$.

Comment: I think that a very helpful step in finding the answer to your question would be writing out the definition of a map $\phi: B_n \to A$ (for arbitrary $n$).

Comment: Is the idea here that you cannot really create a map that is a bijection? I mean since A is uncountable. And, also, I am not sure how it could be that n-tuples are mapped to sequences.

Comment: No, that wasn't quite my point.  There is a "common sense" map that I thought you had in mind, i.e. 
$$
(a_1,\dots,a_n) \mapsto a_1,\dots,a_n,0,0,\dots
$$
then the question becomes whether taking the union of all such sequences gives us $A$

Comment: Ultimately, though, $A$ is uncountable and $\bigcup B_n$ is countable, so as you say there can be no bijection

Comment: Your intuition that "they are the same set" isn't quite right because $A$ contains *infinite* sequences, whereas the natural injection from $\bigcup B_n$ to $A$ only gives *finite* sequences. Indeed, the diagonalisation argument only works if you can either prove that your diagonal sequence is finite, or you assume you can enumerate infinite sequences.